# Set Display Settings in Ubuntu 18.04 from Command Line

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, display-manager

I have several different places that I use my laptop, each with a different combination of monitors or projectors.  I can set it up just fine using the Displays setting UI ($ gnome-control-center display).  However, as a programmer, I figure that there must be a way to do it from the command line, so I can make bash alias that sets it up for the projector room, my office, the hotelling office, etc.

Is there a command line version of gnome-control-center that can set the values?  I took a look at the control center source and it looks like the information is in there (cc-display-config.h), I just need to write it out and read it in.  Sounds like a a fair bit of work, but I figured that someone had done it before.

Comment: I'm a bit out of touch with things gnome - does it still create a `~/.config/monitors.xml` file? if so, you could write a simple script to manage multiple such files

Comment: That file is there.  I'll google to see if it is something that I can use, in terms of storing particular useful ones and then re-using  as needed.  Thanks for the pointer.